# tensorflow object detection API Error at windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

I changed some sources to be real time object detection in the object_detection_tutorial provided by the tensorflow object detection API. However, the following error occurred. What is the solution?

The code that caused the problem is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if tf.__version__ < '1.4.0':
  raise ImportError('Please upgrade your tensorflow installation to v1.4.* or later!')

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")

# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# # Model preparation 

# ## Variables
# 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_CKPT` to point to a new .pb file.  
# 
# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90


# ## Download Model

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())


# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


# ## Helper code

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# # Detection

# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
    detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    while True:
       ret, image_np = cv2.read()
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
          [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
      cv2.imshow('object detection',cv2.resize(image_np,(800,600)))
      if cv2.waitkey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break;
```

This is the result of running the corresponding source as Anaconda Prompt

```
(tensorflow3_6) c:\Users\MrSong\Downloads\models\research>python object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.py", line 104, in <module>
  label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
File "c:\Users\MrSong\Downloads\models\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 117, in load_labelmap
  label_map_string = fid.read()
File "C:\Users\MrSong\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow3_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 119, in read
  self._preread_check()    
File "C:\Users\MrSong\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow3_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
  compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
File "C:\Users\MrSong\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow3_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
  c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: data\mscoco_label_map.pbtxt : \udcc1\udcf6\udcc1\udca4\udcb5\udcc8 \udcb0\udce6\udcb7θ\udca6 ã\udcc0\udcbb \udcbc\udcf6 \udcbe\udcf8\udcbd\udcc0\udcb4ϴ\udcd9.
; No such process
```

Comment: Have you tried closing some other windows that might be accessing your GPU, then running it again?

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/issues/50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt' in the data folder in 'object_detection' directory. The CONFIG file and the labelmap should be in the same directory.